# Call an Exe file from DLL in VB

Tags: vb.net, dll, exe, erp

My new ERP allow to import DLL's with functions but not EXE's, but the final user needs an exe to import data to the database. It's possible to open my EXE program from the DLL imported from the ERP?

Comment: Code is code.  It does the same thing whether it's in a DLL or an EXE.  The difference is simply that an EXE has an entry point.  If you know how to run an executable from an EXE then you already know how to do it from a DLL.  If you don't know how to do that, that's what you need to find out.

Comment: Ok, and I can pass params to the exe file and get the result from it

Comment: I've created a DLL project and in the Public Class called Class1 i added the following line: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe"), and it doesn't works because it need a declaration

Comment: I very much doubt that that line "need a declaration".  How about you provide the actual error message?

Comment: I think that i needs to create a method, can you help me?

Comment: That's far too vague a description of a problem and writing a method is not something specific enough to be helped with on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process.Start()

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("myExeFile.exe")
```

Comment: I had created a new DLL Project in the public Class and added the code: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("myExeFile.exe") but it crash, it needs a declaration

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question but that line must be inside a method. If you try to paste it in the class you will get an error. It should be    Public Sub MyMethod()
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe")
    End Sub